# ReactJS: Render dynamic Component and pass props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In a DataGridCell component I need to provide ability to point which component should be render content of the cell. Also props needs to be passed into this component.
I tried to do it in the next way (simplified version):

```
import * as React from 'react';
interface IDataGridCellProps {
    data?: any,
    component?: React.Component,
}

export default class DataGridCell extends React.Component<IDataGridCellProps> {
    public render() {
        const Cmp: React.Component<any> = this.props.component as React.Component;
        return (
            <div>
                <Cmp {...this.props.data} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm getting next error:
TS2604: JSX element type 'Cmp' does not have any construct or call signatures

What is wrong and what is the correct way to render dynamic component?

**UPD**
I use then `DataGridCell` component like this:

```
<DataGridCell key={indexCell}
                data={profile}
                component={cell.component}
                />
```

This is in a loop. `cell.component` is in the config and looks like this: `component: Text`. `Text` is our component.

**UPD 2**
So it looks like a problem not in the implementation but in `ts-lint` and `typescript`. I cast component to type `any` and it works now.
Changed line: `const Cmp: any = this.props.component;`

Any more valuable explanation is appreciated.

Comment: How are you using `DataGridCell`? What are you passing in as the `component` prop?

Comment: If `this.props.component` is already a component, you just do  `<div>{this.props.component}</div>`    But if you want to pass props to this, you need to pass a class not a component,..  IOW, from the calling side you would do -> `<DataGridCell component={MyComponent}/>` and not `<DataGridCell component={<MyComponent/>}`

Comment: @MattWay, please have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be done like this:

```
interface IDataGridCellProps
{
  data?: any;
  component?: React.ComponentType<any>;
}

export default class DataGridCell extends React.Component<IDataGridCellProps> {
  public render()
  {
    const Cmp = this.props.component;
    if (Cmp)
    {
      return (
        <div>
          <Cmp {...this.props.data} />
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

TypeScript now handles properly generics in jsx so it can be:

```
interface IDataGridCellProps<T>
{
  data?: T;
  component?: React.ComponentType<T>;
}

export default class DataGridCell<T> extends React.Component<IDataGridCellProps<T>> {
  public render()
  {
    const Cmp = this.props.component;

    if (this.props.data === undefined || Cmp === undefined)
    {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Cmp {...this.props.data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Can you also clarify one thing here? The generic type is never known and I would need to define the type of  `public static defaultProps: IDataGridCellProps<T> `. How to resolve this?

Comment: I don't know what is the defaultProps you are talking about. The generic type T is inferred by the compiler when DataGridCell is used and you don't have to explicitly declare it.

Comment: Now I got what you meant. It works just fine. Thank you